# Перевод строки на int java

Tags: java, строки

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста почему у меня срабатывает исключение:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a[] = new byte[100];
        String s=null;
        int sum;
        try {
            System.in.read(a);
            s=new String (a);
            sum = Integer.parseInt(s);

            System.out.print(sum);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2
                                                                                              "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at test.main(test.java:14)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: А что вы вводите?

Comment: Я должен вывести то что написал на команде. Что вы можете порекомендовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы считываете массив байтов размером 100 методом [`InputStream.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])):

```
System.in.read(a);
```

Этот метод считывает все доступные символы (не больше 100), в том числе и символ переноса строки. Этот перенос строки видно и в сообщении об ошибке:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2
      *** строка еще не закрылась, крутите вправо                                                                                                 " а вот и конец строки ***
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Текст, состоящий из двух строк не является числом, о чем и говорит сообщение об ошибке.

Чтобы не считывать перенос строки можно:

- считывать по одному байту, отбрасывая ненужные символы;
- удалить лишние символы уже из полученной строки;
- использовать классы, которые предоставляют готовые методы для считывания слов/чисел, например, [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String s = scanner .next(); //считывает слово
 //а можно сразу
 sum = scanner .nextInt();
```